# macro's rewrite to follow the c++ convention

Tags: c++, c, macros

How can I rewrite the following macro so that they actually followed c++ convention? (that in C++, we prefer to use `typedef`, `const` and `inline` functions). 
Here is the macro.

```
#define UBYTE unsigned char
#define ULONG unsigned long
#define FALSE 0
#define COMPRESS_MAX_COM 0x70000000
#define COMPRESS_MAX_ORG (1024-COMPRESS_OVERRUN)
#define MAX_RAW_GROUP (16*MAX_RAW_ITEM)
#define U(X) ((ULONG) X)
```

How can I change the above macro into the c++ convention?

Comment: @brokenfoot you had left `@brokenmarkup` there :)

Comment: `using` is probably preferable to `typedef` in C++ these days.

Comment: C++ doesn't really have "the convention". Your code is perfectly valid in C++; whether it's tasteful is a matter of opinion.

Comment: See the `stdint.h` or `cstdint` header files.

Comment: You can't do much until you have `COMPRESS_OVERRUN` defined; it isn't on display.  Ditto `MAX_RAW_ITEM`.  The `U(X)` macro isn't really well written: `U(a ? b : c)` doesn't always produce an `unsigned long` (for example, if `b` and `c` are `double`, it produces a `double`).

Comment: What's the desired behavior of `U(1-4)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `typedef` or `using` (C++11) instead of `#define` for the types, then use `const` for constants. The functions can be defined as `constexpr` in C++11.

```
typedef unsigned char UBYTE;  // using UBYTE = unsigned char; // C++11
typedef unsigned long ULONG;
const unsigned int FALSE=0; // constexpr usigned int FALSE = 0; // C++11
const ULONG COMPRESS_MAX_COM=0x70000000;
const ULONG COMPRESS_MAX_ORG=(1024-COMPRESS_OVERRUN); // if COMPRESS_OVERRUN is const
const ULONG MAX_RAW_GROUP=(16*MAX_RAW_ITEM); // again if MAX_RAW_ITEM is a previously defined const
#define U(X) ((ULONG) X) // this can stay as it is
```

or

```
template <typename T>
ULONG U(const T& x)
{
    return static_cast<ULONG>(x);
}
```

so `U(some type T)` will return a cast-to-ULONG of its argument of type `T`.

Comment: #typedef UBYTE unsigned char 
 #typedef ULONG unsigned long 
 #typedef FALSE 0 
 #typedef COMPRESS_MAX_COM 0x70000000 
 #typedef COMPRESS_MAX_ORG (1024-COMPRESS_OVERRUN) 
 #typedef MAX_RAW_GROUP (16*MAX_RAW_ITEM) 
 #typedef U(X) ((ULONG) X) 
so it should look like this isnt it

Comment: Variables can also be `constexpr`.

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: why we keep #define U(X) ((ULONG) X) as it is ?

Comment: see my edit, you can keep it if you want, C++ allows #defines. If you want pure C++ without any pre-processing, use a template cast. And if you have a C++11-compliant compiler, use `constexpr` instead of `const`, as @Chnossos mentioned.

Comment: @Jarod42, type is used only as a parameter, so that `U` can accept any type. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Ohhhh yeah :) Sorry, you are absolutely right :) Corrected it.

Comment: how about the other 3? COMPRESS_MAX_COM and COMPRESS_MAX_ORG and MAX_RAW_GROUP, what type we can use for these?

Comment: depends on how you'll use them in you application. `COMPRESS_MAX_COM` is definitely a `unsigned long`, not sure about the other ones, they are probably `(long) int` or `unsigned (long) int`s

Comment: `#define U(X) ((ULONG) X)` should be `#define U(X) ((ULONG)(X))`, if you are keeping the define version

Answer (score 0):

You should consider integer size, especially if you are using these definitions in an interface.

For example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint8_t UBYTE;  // using UBYTE = unsigned char; // C++11
typedef uint32_t ULONG;
const uint32_t FALSE=0; // constexpr unsigned int FALSE = 0; // C++11
```

The other definitions @vsoftco gave above are great:

```
const ULONG COMPRESS_MAX_COM=0x70000000;
const ULONG COMPRESS_MAX_ORG=(1024-COMPRESS_OVERRUN); // if COMPRESS_OVERRUN is const
const ULONG MAX_RAW_GROUP=(16*MAX_RAW_ITEM); // again if MAX_RAW_ITEM is a previously defined const
#define U(X) ((ULONG) X) // this can stay as it is
```